# Removing all elements from List<T>

Tags: c#, removeall

I'm trying to remove all elements when the user clicks Yes on a messagebox, but I'm not really sure how to remove all items on a buttonclick. I am able to remove element at index but not all elements.

This is how I successfully remove element at index:

```
public void DeleteAt(int anIndex)
{
    if(CheckIndex(anIndex))
    m_list.RemoveAt(anIndex);
}
```

But I want to remove **all** elements.
I tried doing this:

```
public void DeleteAll()
{
      m_list.RemoveAll();
}
```

But it's not working, it's saying that there needs to be a parameter to `RemoveAll();` but I don't know what kind of parameter.

Comment: List.Clear() only deletes the items from the listbox, but it doesn't actually remove the elements from the List<T>

Comment: If you don't know what method to use or don't know how to use a certain method, I would recommend reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @John.P Where does the listbox comes from? It is not there in your question!

Comment: if all else fails read the manual

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`List<T>.Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you want:

> Removes all elements from the List.

So in your example:

```
public void DeleteAll()
{
    m_list.Clear(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is `m_list` a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Then the [`Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method removes all the items from it, which is what you want.

As for [`List<T>.RemoveAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the documentation is pretty clear about it. Basically you need to pass a delegate method that "filters" your list. In your case, you could pass something that always returns `true`, but there's no need for it, as you already have `Clear()`